# list of custom post by custom field in frontend

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode

I'm trying to list the custom posts associated with a client.

I have a CPT "assessment"
with an ACF custom field "customer".

The short code would go to a specific page "my assessments"

So far I was able to do the following:

```
function lista_mis_valoraciones_shortcode() { 
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type' => 'assessment',
    'meta_key'  => 'customer',
    'meta_value'    => $current_user_id
));


// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $the_query->have_posts() ){
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img src="<?php the_field('event_thumbnail'); ?>" />
                the_title(); 
        
    endwhile; 

endif; 
}
wp_reset_query();    // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). 

}
add_shortcode( 'lista_mis_valoraciones', 'lista_mis_valoraciones_shortcode' );
```

Any kind of help is welcome.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you've mixed up two methods of querying posts.

You're querying the correct posts here:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type' => 'assessment',
    'meta_key'  => 'customer',
    'meta_value'    => $current_user_id
));
```

But then the posts you're actually looping through are queried here:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Where `$args` is undefined and has nothing to do with the previously queried posts. You can pass the same arguments to `WP_Query` as `get_posts()`, but with `posts_per_page`, rather than `numberposts`:

```
function lista_mis_valoraciones_shortcode() {
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $the_query       = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type'      => 'assessment',
            'meta_key'       => 'customer',
            'meta_value'     => $current_user_id,
        )
    );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php the_field( 'event_thumbnail' ); ?>" />
            <?php the_title(); ?>

            <?php
        endwhile;
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode( 'lista_mis_valoraciones', 'lista_mis_valoraciones_shortcode' );
```

Note the other changes I made:

- You had mixed in HTML with PHP with the `<img>` and `<a>` tags. To output HTML you need to close the PHP tags with `?>` and open them again with `<?php` when you're done.
- You had a stray `endif` that needed to be removed.
- `wp_reset_postdata()` is more appropriate in this case than `wp_reset_query()`.

Comment: Thank you Jacob for your answer and for correcting my mistakes.

In the next part I copied the example from which I base myself instead of the one I should go to, but I don't know how to adapt it.

Instead of the event image:
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php the_field( 'event_thumbnail' ); ?>" />
            <?php the_title(); ?>

That you filter custom posts by:
the_field ('number_of_valuation') and the_field ('date_and_time_of_valuation').

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, but it sounds like something that should be a new question.

Comment: Sorry, I am communicating thanks to the google translator.
From what I understand, once you do the query, it shows all the posts with their event thumbnail and title.
When copying the code, I must have overlooked this ...
But I just need only the title. Since not my CPT have no event thumbnail .
I tried deleting the html code from the image but nothing appears.